# How do I programatically alter a Groovy/Gradle file in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, gradle

My goal is to alter an Android build.gradle file programatically. I want to add a plugin on a specific line, and then a dependency in a specific `dependency`-section.

My question is does Groovy contain a parser for its own language? How can I easily modify a build.gradle-file (or any Groovy file) programatically?

Comment: Take a look at the source code of the groovyConsole. The console has an option to show you the ast (abstract syntax tree) of your source. But don't expect this to be an easy solution to your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks.. But there's no way to go from AST back to source code, is it?  (I've only skimmed http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations)

Comment: No easy way. At least, you now know that hrails contains its own parser :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AfaIk, programatically altering a groovy file is not easy. There are parsers like the build in AST parser or config slurper, but there is no easy way back to code. Aand all those parsers throw not only the formatting, but also the comments away. The resulting source wouldn't be what you expect.

Grails plugins often have the same problem. The solution is to use regular expressions in order to change the code or to avoid changing the code at all (adding an additional config instead of changing the original).

Comment: I would be careful stating "Regular expressions is the solution", but I like your hint of avoiding to change the code at all by adding additional config(s). I realize Gradle is flexible in that you may define i.e. the `dependencies`-section multiple times.

Comment: If that is an option, I guess it's the best way

Comment: I solved my concrete problem by appending some lines at the end of the build.gradle file, ignoring whatever is in it initially. Might not work for every use case, but worked for me so I'm accepting your answer ;)